# How to allow only double backslash in email with Regex?

Tags: c#, regex, email

I am trying to accept `\\` and `/` before the `@` symbol in our email like usernames. 
Below is the current Regex that we are using:

`^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$`

The reason why I only want to allow double backslash is that I want the string to be escaped by the time I use this regex to validate if it is a valid username.

Valid and Invalid Use Cases:

1. `hello\\world@email.com` is **valid**.
2. `hello\world@email.com` is **invalid**.
3. `hello/world@gmil.com` is **valid**.
4. `hello@email.com` is **valid**.

I have tried the following regular expression but it allowed single backslash also:

`^([\w-(\\\\)/\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$`

Comment: only before the at symbol?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Good question. Yes, that's right!

Comment: Is `hello\/world@email.com` valid?

Comment: C# escapes backslashes with another `\` so nope.

Comment: Tarik check my ans .. its working for me ..

Comment: What was exactly happening was you have put the logic inside [] square bracket so it become range instead of expression '\\' . Hence it was allowing \ also as a valid character. ..

Comment: @Tarik if you got the answer please mark it checked ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How it should be escaped depends a little on what language you are using, but here you go:

```
^(([-\w\/\.]|\\\\)+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$
```

[See it in action](http://rubular.com/r/AoX4AkoqCh)

All I did is add a forward slash in the first group `\/` and add two back slashes as an alternative `|\\\\`.

---

Here is the C# escaped version:

```
^(([-\\w\\/\\.]|\\\\\\\\)+)@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.)|(([\\w-]+\\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\\]?)$
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This one ..

```
^([\w]+)((\\\\)*(/)*(\.)*)([\w]*)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add negative lookahead at the start.

```
^(?![^@]*?(?:\\\\\\|(?<!\\)\\(?!\\)))([\w-\\\\/.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eJ0aN4/4)

```
@"(?m)^(?![^@]*?(?:\\\\\\|(?<!\\)\\(?!\\)))([\w-\\\\/.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$"
```

Comment: Matches `hello\/world@email.com` too.

Comment: It worked but not in C# language. I should have specified the fact that I was using C#.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: It was not me, but adding +1.